# I can't load my game on GTA V

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I wanted to replay a mission - but in the middle of it I changed my mind and loaded my saved game.

But instead of loading my game it loaded the first mission. I restarted the game and the Playstation but it's still loading the first mission.

What can I do?

Comment: Wait... how did you decide to load your save in the middle of loading a replay mission? Can you please clarify? In addition, putting "thanks" or the like on the end of your questions is generally frowned upon.

Comment: I decided to load my game during the mission I was replaying not during the loading. What if I delete the saved data called replay mission?

Comment: Can you backup saves to usb or extra storage?

Comment: Yes I've done that before